# Why multiply the text when I am trying web-scraping a table with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web-scraping a table from a website, and everything is fine, run without error, but when i open it in csv, i see that there are a multiple web-scraping: text+table, when i need just the table which one I am web-scraping.

[image]

The table start from the 53. row and I don't understand that. 
Why my code is web-scraping the text too and not only the table?

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import unicodecsv as csv

filename = r'output.csv'

resultcsv = open(filename, "wb")
output = csv.writer(resultcsv, delimiter=';', quotechar='"',
                    quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='latin-1')

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("intl.accept_languages", "en-us")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bud/arrivals")
time.sleep(10)
html_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, "html.parser")
print(soup)

table = soup.find('table', { "class" : "table table-condensed table-hover data-table m-n-t-15" })

datatable = []
for record in table.find_all('tr'):
    temp_data = []
    for data in record.find_all('td'):
        temp_data.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))
    datatable.append(temp_data)

output.writerows(datatable)

resultcsv.close()
```

Comment: could you inspect the value of datatable before you write to csv?

Comment: I fixed your code to remove all the redundant imports etc to improve readability.

Comment: Where did you fix it? I can't see it :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table contains all these lines in `tr` tags, that's why they append with the line you want.

You need to filter the class of the tags you expect, in your case this should work :

```
for record in table.find_all('tr', class_="hidden-xs hidden-sm ng-scope"):
    temp_data = []
    for data in record.find_all("td"):
        temp_data.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))
    datatable.append(temp_data)
```